# referring instance variables in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was confused about the different ways to access instance variables in rails models. For example, this will work:

```
def add_calories(ingredient)


    self.total_calories += ingredient.calories

    p total_calories

end
```

However this will results in errors:

```
def add_calories(ingredient)

    total_calories += ingredient.calories

end



Error: NoMethodError: undefined method "+" for nil:NilClass
```

Also this won't work either.

```
def add_calories(ingredient)

    total_calories = total_calories + ingredient.calories

end
```

If I can access the instance variable without self in the first case, how come that in the second case, total_calories becomes nil?

Could it be that the default value for total_calories is set to 0? However if that's the case, why does self.total_calories work?

```
t.integer  "total_calories", default: 0
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848332/instance-variables-in-a-rails-model) but it doesn't really explain why the third case won't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not so much instance variables here as accessible attributes. All attributes are contained in an instance_variable called `@attributes` which is actually a `Hash` as for why you have to call the getter methods with an explicit receiver I am not sure maybe someone else can assist with that part

Comment: It works in the first case without an explicit receiver "self" when I used it in a print statement. So that makes me think that self is optional. However in the second and the third case, it wouldn't work without self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like less of a question about instance variable access in Rails and more a question about "setter" methods in Ruby (in your case, using the `total_calories=` method).  Information about why an explicit `self` receiver is needed for setter methods is covered in other Stack Overflow answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44715/567863).

In summary, though, the issue is that the intention of the statement `total_calories = something` could be ambiguous: are you defining a new local variable or calling the setter?  Calling `self.total_calories = something` explicitly says you want to call the setter, while leaving off `self` and calling `total_calories = something` says you want a new local variable.

I think your third example should work if you change the method content to use both getter and setter methods explicitly:

```
def add_calories(ingredient)
  self.total_calories = total_calories + ingredient.calories
end
```